# $M \lambda=\mu \implies \lambda \geq \mu$, where $\lambda, \mu$ are partitions of $n$, and $M$ is a $n \times n$ double stochastic matrix

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I have $\lambda, \mu$ as 2 partitions of $n \ (=|\lambda|=|\mu|)$, and  I have been given that $M \lambda=\mu$, where M is a $n \times n$ double stochastic matrix i.e. $$\sum_im_{ij}=\sum_jm_{ij}=1$$

I have to show that $$\lambda \geq \mu  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (\text{i.e.} \sum_{k=1}^i\lambda_k \geq \sum_{k=1}^i\mu_k \ , \ \forall i \geq 1)$$

Now, we know that $$\sum_jm_{ij}\lambda_j=\mu_i \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ i\geq1$$
For $i=1$
$$\mu_1 = \sum_jm_{1j}\lambda_j \leq \lambda_1 \Big(\sum_jm_{1j} \Big)=\lambda_1$$

But I'm unable to proceed with proving the general inequality, any help will be appreciated. This is an example from Macdonald's *Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials*

Comment: First: what is a partition? a positive vector with the sum of elements equal $n$ and sorted in decreasing order?
Second: $\lambda \ge \mu$ means that the partial sum of $\lambda$ are greater than the ones of $\mu$? reformulate the definition, please

Comment: Yes, precisely what you said. Fixed

Comment: Hint: Lemma 1 in http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h19097p140145 (the "symmetric majorization criterion") shows that you only need to check that every real $x$ satisfies $\sum_{k=1}^n \left|\lambda_k - x\right| \geq \sum_{k=1}^n \left|\mu_k - x\right|$. But the triangle inequality shows that each $i \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$ satisfies $\sum_{k=1}^n m_{i,k} \left|\lambda_k - x\right| \geq \left|\mu_i - x\right|$ (because if you omit the absolute values, then this becomes an equality). Sum this up over all $i$, and you get the inequality you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^i \mu_k = \sum_{k=1}^i (M\lambda)_k = \sum_{k=1}^i \sum_j m_{kj}\lambda_j = \sum_j \lambda_j \cdot \sum_{k=1}^i m_{kj}
$$
Define $p_j = \frac 1i\sum_{k=1}^i m_{kj}$. From the hypotesis you get $p_j\le 1/i$ and $\sum_j p_j= 1$.
$$
\sum_{k=1}^i \frac 1i\mu_k =  \sum_j \lambda_j p_j = \sum_{k=1}^i \frac 1i\lambda_k  - \sum_{k=1}^i \lambda_k \left(\frac 1i -p_k\right) +\sum_{k=i+1}^n \lambda_k p_k
$$
$$
\le \sum_{k=1}^i \frac 1i\lambda_k  - \lambda_i\sum_{k=1}^i \left(\frac 1i -p_k\right) +\lambda_{i+1}\sum_{k=i+1}^n  p_k 
$$
but $\sum_{k=1}^i \left(\frac 1i -p_k\right) = 1 - \sum_{k=1}^i p_k = \sum_{k=i+1}^n  p_k $, so
$$= \sum_{k=1}^i \frac 1i\lambda_k  -(\lambda_{i}-\lambda_{i+1})\sum_{k=i+1}^n  p_k 
\le \sum_{k=1}^i \frac 1i\lambda_k
$$